# How to connect to a SMSC simulator through android?

Tags: java, android

I'm currently working on and Android project where any incoming text messages get sent to an SMSC Simulator. Currently, in my android project, I am unable to connect to the Simulator.

What libraries would I use to connect?

I am using the simulator found here:
https://github.com/cornet/logica-smscsim

As of now, the Simulator is set to port 2075 and I use the following line of code to send a message:

```
smsManager.sendDataMessage(number, null, (short)port, message.getBytes(), null, null);
```

Where port is 2075.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phone can't connect to an SMSC simulator using that class, that class sends SMS (messages) from your phone, over the air, to your service provider who will, in turn, forward them from their SMSC to the SMSC of the recipient and then to the recipient.

If you want to connect to a simulator you'll have to write or find a class that implements either SMPP or UCP and then utilize that class for connection/submission/etc.

Comment: So there is no chance of me sending an SMS to a SMSC Simulator without the Simulator having the client portion available? (i.e. having the phone connected as a client is the only way for it to receive)

Comment: The problem is not the simulator, it's that your phone has to implement SMPP

Comment: I see, I'll have to look into this more then. Thanks for your help Kevin

Comment: You're welcome - there are numerous implementations of SMPP that you should be able to find via a web search, they would be a good place to start.  I can't speak to any of them in particular, but given that it's been around for 20+ years there shouldn't be any difficulty finding a good one.